# How to properly write yaml file for ros control

Tags: ros, ros-control, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Isn't their any tutorial to write exactly the syntax/rules to write a yaml file for ros controller launch. I am dealing with this type of files first time, and i didn't found tutorial for this yaml file like urdf, sdf, launch and all others. Although by studying the pre existing yaml file i can learn how to make them again, but isn't their any rules to write this file like urdf files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251419/how-to-properly-write-yaml-file-for-ros-control/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2017-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

YAML is a standard used by many software packages, so it's described in many sites. The official site is here: http://www.yaml.org/

There's a [short list of examples in the ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/YAML%20Overview).

I found [this online parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) to be quite helpful; you can quickly check to see if your YAML snippets will be parsed correctly.

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2017-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

I gathered this by looking at header files in the ros_control github repository:

```
# Effort controllers -----------------------------------
effort_joint_position_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
  joint: joint_1
  pid: {p: 0.25, d: 1.0, i: 0.0, i_max: 0, i_min: 0}

effort_joint_group_position_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointGroupPositionController
  joints:
     - joint_1
     - joint_2

effort_joint_velocity_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointVelocityController
  joint: joint_1
  pid: {p: 0.25, d: 1.0, i: 0.0, i_max: 0, i_min: 0}

effort_joint_effort_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointEffortController
  joint: joint_1

effort_joint_group_effort_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointEffortController
  joints:
     - joint_1
     - joint_2


# Position controllers -----------------------------------
position_joint_position_controller:
  type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
  joint: joint_1

position_joint_group_position_controller:
  type: position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController
  joints:
     - joint_1
     - joint_2


# Velocity controllers -----------------------------------
velocity_joint_position_controller:
  type: velocity_controllers/JointPositionController
  joint: joint_1
  pid: {p: 0.25, d: 1.0, i: 0.0, i_max: 0, i_min: 0}

velocity_joint_velocity_controller:
  type: velocity_controllers/JointVelocityController
  joint: joint_1

velocity_joint_group_velocity_controller:
  type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController
  joints:
     - joint_1
     - joint_2
```

Please note that i_max and i_min are optional parameters. They are not needed to be specified in a pid controller.

The syntax for trajectory controllers can be found at the bottom of their wiki page:
http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller

Here is an example on how to send a command to a controller:

`$ rostopic pub -1 my_eff_joint_pos_controller/command std_msgs/Float64 "data: -0.7"`

Hope it is helpful!